# Use MongoDB in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with using MongoDB in a docker-compose.
I have a folder "store" and a folder "mongo". A Python code of the store has to use MongoDB but the command "docker-compose up" raises an error "ERROR: Named volume "mongodb:mongo:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section."
Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongodb:./mongo
    
  store:
    image: store:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "6381:6381"
```

Thanks in advance,
Have a nice day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705017/create-named-docker-volume-with-docker-compose

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162897/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-using-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `volumes` section to your compose file, where you declare the volume. Like this

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongodb:./mongo
    
  store:
    image: store:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "6381:6381"

volumes:
  mongodb:
```